# deserialize json object from protobuf return empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, protocol-buffers, scalapb

I am parsing the bahir mqtt payload serialized via protobuf using scalapb in spark scala but the parsed json only contains first json object and others are empty.

- Spark version: 2.3.0
- Scala version: 2.11.8
- Protobuf version: 2
- sparksql-scalapb version: 0.8.0

```
import spark.implicits._
val parsedData = lines.select("payload").as[Array[Byte]].map(ParseData.parseFrom(_))
```

The proto file

```
syntax = "proto2";
option java_package = "protobuf";

message ParseData {
    required int64 timestamp = 1;
    message METRICS {
        required string name = 1;
        optional int64 timestamp = 2;
        optional string dataType = 3;
        optional double value = 4;
    }
    repeated METRICS metrics = 2;
    required int32 seq = 3;
}
```

The result I am getting

```
+-------------+--------------------+---+
|timestamp    |metrics             |seq|
+-------------+--------------------+---+
|1567158851979|[[T05,,,], [T06,,,]]|54 |
+-------------+--------------------+---+
```

But the expected result is

```
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|timestamp    |metrics                                                                                                      
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---+
|1567158851979|[[T05,1566920552229,Float,34.56], [T06,1566920552229,Float,32.5]]|54 |
+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+---+
```

**Update-1**

The payload incoming message before serialization looks likes this:

```
{
"metrics" : [{
"name" : "T05",
"timestamp" : 1566920552229,
"dataType" : "Float",
"value" : 34.56
},
{
"name" : "T06",
"timestamp" : 1566920552229,
"dataType" : "Float",
"value" : 32.5
}]
}
```

The MQTT server is using eclipse tahu project which uses protobuf to serialize the payload.

**Update 2**

Here is the code:

```
val lines = spark.readStream
      .format("org.apache.bahir.sql.streaming.mqtt.MQTTStreamSourceProvider")
      .option("topic", topic)
      .option("username", username)
      .option("password", password)
      .load(brokerUrl)

import spark.implicits._
val parseLines = lines.select("payload").as[Array[Byte]].map(ParseData.parseFrom(_))

lines.printSchema()

val data = parseLines.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .start()


 data.awaitTermination()
```

Schema and Sample of streamed data

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- payload: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)

+---+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|id |topic                     |payload                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |timestamp          |
+---+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|0  |spBv1.0/XYZ/DDATA/Tahu/ABC|[08 83 E8 99 99 CE 2D 12 53 0A 3F 46 69 6E 69 73 68 69 6E 67 2F 54 72 69 6F 2F 66 61 63 65 53 43 36 30 30 2F 4D 45 53 50 72 6F 63 65 73 73 54 61 67 73 2F 68 6F 6C 65 43 6F 72 72 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 4C 6F 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 31 18 D2 AE 99 99 CE 2D 20 09 38 00 4A 00 65 9A D9 19 43 12 57 0A 43 46 69 6E 69 73 68 69 6E 67 2F 54 72 69 6F 2F 66 61 63 65 53 43 36 30 30 2F 4D 45 53 50 72 6F 63 65 73 73 54 61 67 73 2F 68 6F 6C 65 43 6F 72 72 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 4C 6F 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 44 65 6C 74 61 18 EA AF 99 99 CE 2D 20 09 38 00 4A 00 65 9A D9 19 43 12 49 0A 35 4D 69 78 50 72 65 70 61 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 42 6F 6E 64 4D 69 78 69 6E 67 2F 73 69 67 6E 61 6C 73 4D 45 53 2F 6D 69 78 65 72 54 69 6D 65 45 6C 61 70 73 65 64 18 BA A9 99 99 CE 2D 20 03 38 00 4A 00 50 CD E2 82 11 12 4B 0A 37 4D 69 78 50 72 65 70 61 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 42 6F 6E 64 4D 69 78 69 6E 67 2F 73 69 67 6E 61 6C 73 4D 45 53 2F 6D 69 78 65 72 54 69 6D 65 52 65 6D 61 69 6E 69 6E 67 18 EB A9 99 99 CE 2D 20 03 38 00 4A 00 50 F1 D6 82 11 12 4C 0A 38 46 69 6E 69 73 68 69 6E 67 2F 54 72 69 6F 2F 31 73 74 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 2F 53 69 67 6E 61 6C 73 2F 46 49 52 53 54 5F 43 4F 4E 54 52 4F 4C 5F 54 45 4D 50 5F 45 4E 47 18 EE D2 F5 9B CE 2D 20 09 38 00 4A 00 65 9D A2 02 42 12 47 0A 33 46 69 6E 69 73 68 69 6E 67 2F 54 72 69 6F 2F 66 61 63 65 53 43 36 30 30 2F 73 69 67 6E 61 6C 73 2F 4D 6F 74 6F 72 5F 43 75 72 72 65 6E 74 5F 41 6D 70 73 18 EE D2 F5 9B CE 2D 20 09 38 00 4A 00 65 22 B7 47 41 18 17]|2019-08-30 17:30:43|
|0  |spBv1.0/XYZ/DDATA/Tahu/ABC|[08 EB EF 99 99 CE 2D 12 49 0A 35 4D 69 78 50 72 65 70 61 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 42 6F 6E 64 4D 69 78 69 6E 67 2F 73 69 67 6E 61 6C 73 4D 45 53 2F 6D 69 78 65 72 54 69 6D 65 45 6C 61 70 73 65 64 18 A3 B1 99 99 CE 2D 20 03 38 00 4A 00 50 CE E2 82 11 12 4B 0A 37 4D 69 78 50 72 65 70 61 72 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 42 6F 6E 64 4D 69 78 69 6E 67 2F 73 69 67 6E 61 6C 73 4D 45 53 2F 6D 69 78 65 72 54 69 6D 65 52 65 6D 61 69 6E 69 6E 67 18 D3 B1 99 99 CE 2D 20 03 38 00 4A 00 50 F2 D6 82 11 18 18]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |2019-08-30 17:30:44|
+---+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the payload?

Comment: @cocolapin01 In the question you are referring to JSON, but from the code it shows that you are parsing bytes into case classes - can you correct the question?  It is possibly a problem with the payload - maybe you are having missing the data in the input.

Comment: @thesamet I made some changes to the question, the schema of the payload is binary and I must use an external parser to parse it correctly. I don't want to read it as JSON because I will transform the payload.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the actual payload input you are loading into `lines` and the code you use to load it?

Comment: @thesamet added the missing info

Comment: I am getting error while using oneof value in proto file

Comment: You mention an error when using a oneof value, but you haven't specified how you use a oneof value and which error you are getting, so it is difficult to help. However, if you change the proto schema and try to parse data that was serialized before the change, then errors are expected in certain cases. In case this is helpful, here are the type of changes that are supported for proto2: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to isolate the problem. We can start by taking Spark out of the equation.

If we take the payload you provided and try to parse it:

```
val b: Array[Byte] = Array(0x08, 0x83, 0xE8, 0x99, 0x99, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x12, 0x53, 0x0A, 0x3F, 0x46, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x73, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x54, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2F, 0x66, 0x61, 0x63, 0x65, 0x53, 0x43, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2F, 0x4D, 0x45, 0x53, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0x54, 0x61, 0x67, 0x73, 0x2F, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x72, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x4C, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x31, 0x18, 0xD2, 0xAE, 0x99, 0x99, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x09, 0x38, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x65, 0x9A, 0xD9, 0x19, 0x43, 0x12, 0x57, 0x0A, 0x43, 0x46, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x73, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x54, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2F, 0x66, 0x61, 0x63, 0x65, 0x53, 0x43, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2F, 0x4D, 0x45, 0x53, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x65, 0x73, 0x73, 0x54, 0x61, 0x67, 0x73, 0x2F, 0x68, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x65, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x72, 0x65, 0x63, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x4C, 0x6F, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x44, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x74, 0x61, 0x18, 0xEA, 0xAF, 0x99, 0x99, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x09, 0x38, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x65, 0x9A, 0xD9, 0x19, 0x43, 0x12, 0x49, 0x0A, 0x35, 0x4D, 0x69, 0x78, 0x50, 0x72, 0x65, 0x70, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x42, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x4D, 0x69, 0x78, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x73, 0x69, 0x67, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x4D, 0x45, 0x53, 0x2F, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x78, 0x65, 0x72, 0x54, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x45, 0x6C, 0x61, 0x70, 0x73, 0x65, 0x64, 0x18, 0xBA, 0xA9, 0x99, 0x99, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x03, 0x38, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x50, 0xCD, 0xE2, 0x82, 0x11, 0x12, 0x4B, 0x0A, 0x37, 0x4D, 0x69, 0x78, 0x50, 0x72, 0x65, 0x70, 0x61, 0x72, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x2F, 0x42, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x64, 0x4D, 0x69, 0x78, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x73, 0x69, 0x67, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x4D, 0x45, 0x53, 0x2F, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x78, 0x65, 0x72, 0x54, 0x69, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x52, 0x65, 0x6D, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x18, 0xEB, 0xA9, 0x99, 0x99, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x03, 0x38, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x50, 0xF1, 0xD6, 0x82, 0x11, 0x12, 0x4C, 0x0A, 0x38, 0x46, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x73, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x54, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2F, 0x31, 0x73, 0x74, 0x43, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x2F, 0x53, 0x69, 0x67, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x2F, 0x46, 0x49, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x5F, 0x43, 0x4F, 0x4E, 0x54, 0x52, 0x4F, 0x4C, 0x5F, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4D, 0x50, 0x5F, 0x45, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x18, 0xEE, 0xD2, 0xF5, 0x9B, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x09, 0x38, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x65, 0x9D, 0xA2, 0x02, 0x42, 0x12, 0x47, 0x0A, 0x33, 0x46, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x69, 0x73, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x67, 0x2F, 0x54, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6F, 0x2F, 0x66, 0x61, 0x63, 0x65, 0x53, 0x43, 0x36, 0x30, 0x30, 0x2F, 0x73, 0x69, 0x67, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x6C, 0x73, 0x2F, 0x4D, 0x6F, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x5F, 0x43, 0x75, 0x72, 0x72, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x5F, 0x41, 0x6D, 0x70, 0x73, 0x18, 0xEE, 0xD2, 0xF5, 0x9B, 0xCE, 0x2D, 0x20, 0x09, 0x38, 0x00, 0x4A, 0x00, 0x65, 0x22, 0xB7, 0x47, 0x41, 0x18, 0x17).map(_.toByte)

println(ParseData.parseFrom(b).toProtoString)
```

Then the output is:

```
timestamp: 1567179043843
metrics {
  name: "Finishing/Trio/faceSC600/MESProcessTags/holeCorrectionLocation1"
}
metrics {
  name: "Finishing/Trio/faceSC600/MESProcessTags/holeCorrectionLocationDelta"
}
metrics {
  name: "MixPreparation/BondMixing/signalsMES/mixerTimeElapsed"
}
metrics {
  name: "MixPreparation/BondMixing/signalsMES/mixerTimeRemaining"
}
metrics {
  name: "Finishing/Trio/1stControl/Signals/FIRST_CONTROL_TEMP_ENG"
}
metrics {
  name: "Finishing/Trio/faceSC600/signals/Motor_Current_Amps"
}
seq: 23
```

Which shows that only the `name` field inside `metrics` is set, but all the other fields are not set.

This tells us that the data you are passing to `parseFrom` does not have the fields that you expect.

The next step is to investigate why the producer of those messages does not set those fields in the protos before serializing. The problem seems to be on the producer side.

Comment: thank you @thesamet, it was the problem with the input proto. It got fixed.